# Problema con multiples select2 multiple en tabs dentro de asp.net web forms

Tags: select2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Dentro de un formulario asp.net web forms tengo implementado el plugin de select2 multiple, al momento de hacer scroll dentro de la pagina el elemento pierde el estilo y se conoca de la manera en que se muestra en la imagen, alguna manera de resolver el problema?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:

```
function prueba() { 
    $("#prueba").select2({ 
        multiple: true,
        placeholder: "seleccione", 
        //dropdownParent: $("#pruebaa") 
    });
    prueba2();
}

function prueba2() {
    $("#prueba2").select2({ 
        multiple: true,
        placeholder: "seleccione", 
        //dropdownParent: $("#pruebaa2")
    });
}
```

Comment: coloca tu código para ver como lo manejas

Comment: Podrías hacer un gif con [ScreenTogif](http://www.screentogif.com/) ? y subirlo como imagen como parte de la pregunta.... para saber bien a que te refieres con que cambia los estilos... poner código también porfavor

Comment: function prueba() {
            $("#prueba").select2({
                multiple: true,
                placeholder: "seleccione",
                //dropdownParent: $("#pruebaa")
            });
            prueba2();

        }
        function prueba2() {
            $("#prueba2").select2({
                multiple: true,
                placeholder: "seleccione",
                //dropdownParent: $("#pruebaa2")
            });
        }